# this.value in <td> tag showing undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently, i tried to get the `<td>` tag value but its showing undefined. Can I know whats the mistake in my code. I tried searching for other solutions but i couldnt find it till now.

This is my code:

```
    echo "<td value='".$row['CDTitle']."' onclick=\"alert(this.value)\" id=\"clickme\">" . $row['CDTitle'] . "</td>";
```

Once i click on my CD title in the table its showing `Undefined`. Can someone help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Most browsers will only reflect standard attributes as properties and *value* is not a standard attribute of TD elements. Try `this.getAttribute('value')`. It does not seem sensible to embed data in attributes of HTML elements that way (if that is what you're doing), consider using a [*data-* attribute](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), say `data-value`.

Comment: the td not contain any value attribute, so you can't access it using the `this.value`

Comment: @FrayneKonok how can i access it? there should be a way rite

Comment: @RobG are there any ways to achieve it?

Comment: @RobG i tried its showing an error message `fanzine.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined`

Comment: @anonymous5671, do you want to do this using the jQuery?

Comment: @anonymous5671—you should get enough information from [*MDN: Using data attributes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers will only reflect standard attributes as dot properties, and *value* is not a standard attribute of TD elements.

You can use *getAttribute* instead, or you can use a *data-* attribute. There is [help on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) for that. You may end up falling back to *getAttribute* anyway to support IE < 10, but you should still use a *data-* attribute regardless.

Some play code.

```html
<table>
  <tr><td onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('value'))" value="foo">Click me: get attribute
  <tr><td onclick="alert(this.dataset.value)" data-value="foo">Click me: dataset
</table>
```

Of course this is just what the browser gets, how you get the server to serve that is up to you. ;-)